# MVC Scaffolded Views don't validate date properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have created entities from my database with following relevant fields :

```
create table Cow
    ( [ID] int primary key identity
    ...
    , [DateOfBirth] date not null
    , [DateOfArrival] date not null
    ...
    );
```

And used `Add > New scaffolded item > MVC Controller with views, using Entity framework` to generate controller and views.

Everything is nicely generated, but on `Edit` MVC populates fields with dates from database, but if I try to save without modifying anything I get error that date is not formatted correctly (same date that was put there by MVC).

I'm not sure how to fix this.

Here is relevant code from generated template :

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

When I open edit page fields are populated (by that same editor) with :

```
DateOfBirth : 17/08/1991 00:00:00
DateOfArrival : 17/08/1992 00:00:00
```

But he can't parse his own generated values. I get message :

> The field DateOfBirth must be a date.

Comment: make sure that..while inserting and updating,  you are giving the same date format both at ado.net and stored procedure.....

Comment: I mean, everything was generated automatically from database. Also, this is  "JavaScript" validation problem so I can only assume that Editor field is filling in date incorrectly.

Comment: then, in the view you specify particular date format to the textbox...

Comment: Is this just a client side validation error? If so its because the `$.validator` validates dates in `MM/dd/yyyy` format by default, and you need to reconfigure the validator to accept dates in `dd/MM/yyyy` format

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your view

```
// specify your date format here
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { id = "yourID" })
```

**(or)**

Try this in your model class

```
public int ID { get; set; }
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")] // specify your date format here
public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")] // specify your date format here
public DateTime DateOfArrival { get; set; }
```

In the View

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
```

Comment: Added a bit more info. This doesn't work. It just removes time from my date (which is 00 anyway) but JavaScript validation still doesn't accept the date.

Comment: First `TextBoxFor()` does not respect a `[DisplayFormat]` attribute (only `EditorFor` does. Second, using `{0:dd/MM/yyyy}` or a a `[DisplayFormat]` has nothing at all to do with validation - its sole purpose is to display the value in a specific format.